# What is a good reference for the history of medicine?

Tags: history

I am researching the history of human civilization starting in the paleolithic period onward.  I am looking for a reference on the history of medicine-- hopefully starting with our first attempts at medicine and continuing on to the modern age.  I would like a timeline of problems and solutions and how they evolved to where we are now.

Searching Amazon doesn't provide a lot of good books like I was hoping it would.  Given the size of this field, I figured there would be an overwhelming number of books.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

There are not too many books, it's kind of a censored topic.

The best work might be the Cambridge History of Medicine:

The Cambridge History of Medicine

Editor: Roy Porter

Date Published: June 2006
ISBN: 9780521682893

Comment: Downvoted for your first sentence because it's both wrong and makes an unsupported claim.